# technique for finding minima of quadratic surface with an $xy$-term? (without calculus)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am working thru the problems from Spivak's *Calculus*.

Problems 1-17  is a three part problem, asking for the smallest possible value first for a one-variable quadratic expression:

$2x^2-3x+4$

then for a two-variable quadratic expression:

$x^2 - 3x + 2y^2 + 4y + 2$

and finally for a two-variable quadratic expression with an $xy$-term:

$x^2 + 4xy + 5y^2 - 4x - 6y + 7$.

A hint is given for the first part, that one should "complete the square" by re-writing the expression as $2(x-\frac{3}{4})^2+?$.

I see that the first expression is a parabola, and the second expression is a parabolic surface.  In both cases we can add a constant term $k$ so as to shift the curve/surface, turning it into a perfect square.  These perfect squares can easily be solved for zero (i.e., their minimum). So the minimum of the original curve/surface is the negation of the shift $k$, and it occurs at the zero of the shifted curve/surface.

The third expression is also a parabolic surface – but it contains an $xy$ term, so as far as I can tell cannot be turned into a perfect square just by shifting.

Is there some algebraic technique used to find the minimum of a surface like this?  (This problem is from chapter 1; no calculus has actually been introduced yet.)

Comment: Using graphing methods and calculus, one can determine that the answer is $2$, at $(4,-1)$, but I don't think there's an algebraic way to do it. Maybe there's a 'work backwards' solution where you can figure out how to get $x^2+4xy+5y^2-4x-6y+7=2$, but I could not for the life of me figure out a way, either by manipulation (adding and subtracting and grouping variables) or completing the square.

Comment: Hint: “Complete the square” using terms that contain both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This is basically diagonalising a quadratic form by completing squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** You can use substitution $p = x + 2y$, $q = y$ to get rid of $xy$ term and solve it like the case before.

Comment: Thanks!  I see that this works -- I can use it to work out the answer of $2$ at $(4,-1)$... but I am still puzzling over how one would know to use this substitution.  :/

Comment: @billc, well you have term $4xy$ that you want to make disappear. To make it go away, you need substitution of the form $p = ax + by$, thus you want $2ab = 4$. Now, here's the important part: after you square $p$ to get $a^2x^2 + 4ab xy + b^2y^2$, either $a^2x^2$ should be equal to $x^2$ or $b^2y^2$ should be equal to $5y^2$, otherwise you will again have $xy$ term after substitution (or $pq$ term). The example I gave was the simpler one. You could have also tried $p = 2x/\sqrt 5 + y\sqrt 5, q = x$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard way of rotating a conic which eliminates the $xy$ term.  Given $Ax^2+Bxy +Cy^2 +Dx + Ey +F = 0$, solve $$\cot 2t = \frac{A-C}{B}.$$

In your example, $\cot 2t = -1$, so $t = 3\pi/8.$

Then the change of variables $$x = x'\cos t - y'\sin t$$ $$y=x'\sin t +y' \cos t$$

will eliminate the $xy$ term.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Just to clarify -- in the case of my third expression $x^2+4xy+5y^2−4x−6y+7$, don't we have $(A-B)/C = -3/5$?  i.e., $(1-4)/5$?  I don't see where we get $-1$, as in your reply.

Comment: In any case this seems promising, but I need to back up a little and review how to do this kind of substitution.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry there's a typo.  It should be $(A-C)/B.$  I'll edit.  Here's a link to an explanation.  http://www.sparknotes.com/math/precalc/conicsections/section5/